# How to convert Access WHERE clause to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access

We are migrating from MS Access to SQL Server. We have a query which has `WHERE` clause shown here:

```
WHERE 
     (IIf(ATTD_Region_CD = 'ALL', True, IIf(ATTD_Region_CD = 'NI' And    
Region_CD <> '002' AND Region_CD <> '007', True, IIf(ATTD_Region_CD
Region_CD, True, False)))) AND ((SEND_ViaDefault = 'Email') OR (SEND_ViaDefault = 'Fax'));
```

I have done so far as below with my SQL Server `WHERE` clause:

```
Where (0=
case when ATTD_Region_CD ='ALL'
then 1
else
( 
       case
       when 
       (
       ATTD_Region_CD='NI' and Region_CD not in ('002','007')
       )
       then 1 
       else 
            (
           case when     
(ATTD_Region_CD=Region_CD) 
           then 1
           else 
           0 
           end
             )
       end
)      
end
```

)

My data is different then the original one.

Please suggest any solution regarding this that where I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Regards
Ashish Bisht

Answer (score 1):

It is equivalent to:

```
WHERE (
         ATTD_Region_CD = 'ALL' OR 
         (ATTD_Region_CD = 'NI' AND Region_CD <> '002' AND Region_CD <> '007') OR 
         ATTD_Region_CD = Region_CD
      ) AND
      (
         SEND_ViaDefault = 'Email' OR SEND_ViaDefault = 'Fax'
      )
```

As per your question, the main bug you have is `Where (0=`. You should compare to `1` instead. And you missed last part of the predicate `((SEND_ViaDefault = 'Email') OR (SEND_ViaDefault = 'Fax'))`